# Confused in limit ratio

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $\{a_{n}\}$ and  $\{b_{n}\}$ be sequences with all positive terms. If  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges and   $\lim_{n\to∞} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = \infty$ , what does the limit comparison test tell us about  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$?

The possible answers are $a_{n}$ converges, $a_{n}$ diverges, or no conclusion could be made about whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges or diverges.

My reasoning concludes that in order for  $\lim_{n\to∞} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = \infty$, one of two possible conditions must occur — either $b_{n}$ must converge to $0$, or $a_{n}$ must diverge. Since in the problem statement, $b_{n}$ consists of positive terms, and it converges, then the only way for the ration to go to $\infty$ is if $a_{n}$ diverges.

The expected answer is  no conclusion can be made about whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges or diverges.

Where am I missing something?

Comment: Consider $b_n = 1/n^2, a_n=1/n^{3/2}$

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to see that  there is no information about whether $\sum a_n $  converges, is to start with any positive $(a_n)_{n \in N}$ and let $$b_n= \min (2^{-n},a_n2^{-n}).$$. (So  $0<b_n \le 2^{-n}$  and $2^n \le a_n/b_n$ .)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

**Example 1:** $a_n=1/n$ and $b_n=1/n^2$

**Example 2:** $a_n=1/n^2$ and $b_n=1/n^3$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.